# Random number weighted probability - where highest probability is least likely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I want to do a standard picking a random number by weighted probability problem.

**Example Data Set:**

```
Person A    70
Person B    30
Person C    40
```

So normally, these are the probabilities of being picked randomly:

```
Person A    50%
Person B    21%
Person C    29%
```

Now I want to make it so it's inverted, where the higher your probability, the less likely you are to be picked. How do I invert it?

**The way I tried:**

Invert the probabilities

```
Person A    50%
Person B    79%
Person C    71%
```

Add those up `.5 + .79 + .71 = 2`

Divide them by the new total:

```
Person A    .5/2  = 25%
Person B    .79/2 = 40%
Person C    .71/2 = 35%
```

I'm not confident in that answer though - is that the correct way of donig it? Or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: You might want to change your terminology: it's confusing to say "the higher your probability, the less likely you are to be picked". Instead, how about "the higher your *weight*" or "the higher your *score*"?

Answer (score 1):

There's no *right* way to do this - any method of inversion will have its pros and cons. However, a way to do this is to invert the weights before computing probability, i.e.,
$$\textrm{New Weight} = \frac{100}{\textrm{Old Weight}}$$

Using this, the weights will line themselves up in a way that you can use the aforementioned technique to compute weighted probability.